# Bootstrap grid неправильно делит при position fixed

Tags: css, bootstrap

Мне нужно поделить страницу на 2 части. Первая половина должна быть `position: fixed`, а вторая половина будет контент, которая в зависимости от выбора будет увеличиваться или уменьшаться. Проблема в том что при `fixed` `col-sm-6` лезут друг на друга, а не делятся на 2 части.

Как сделать что бы страница оставалась респонсивным под экраны и не заходили в друг друга?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="col-sm-6 affix">
        блоки тут1
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        блоки тут2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот такой пример вышел. Добавил классы Bootstrap экранов и дописал `col-sm-offset-6`.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6 affix">
        блоки тут1
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6 col-sm-offset-6 col-md-offset-6 col-xs-offset-6">
        блоки тут2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Например:

```css
.col-1{
  background: #ccc;
}

.col-2 {
  background: orange;
}


@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .affix {
    position: static !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 affix col-1">
        блоки тут 1
      </div>
    
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-6 col-2">
        блоки тут 2
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```